# ¿Cómo leo la información que está en /usr/bin/env?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Quiero saber adonde a que archivo/directorio me lleva al poner en la terminal por ejemplo `$ python`. Ya sé que poniendo `$ $PATH` me muestra las rutas, pero quiero leerlo en algún archivo o saber donde guarda la información.

Comment: escribe `which python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo de varias formas:

> puedes hacerlo configurandolo en el `~/.bashrc` o en `~/.profile` o en `~/.bash_profile` dependeiendo de que tipo de linux utilizes
>   o directamente en: `/etc/environment`

Comment: Justo necesitaba, gracias

Answer (score 1):

1. Con el built-in `command` y `ls`

   Por ejemplo, en mi caso.

   ```
   $ ls -l $(command -v python) 
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Nov 23  2017 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
   ```
2. Con `readlink`

   ```
   $ readlink -f $(command -v python)
   /usr/bin/python2.7
   ```

Con `command -v programa` se muestra el archivo que se va a ejecutar al llamar *programa*, pero no se ejecuta.

`readlink` sigue los enlaces simbólicos y la opción `-f` prefiere que todos, menos la última ruta a la que dirija en enlace, exista, a diferencia de la opción `-e`.

Y bueno, se sabe lo que hace `ls -l`

Si, después de probar lo anterior, pones en tu terminal `command -v python`, verás la diferencia puesto que la salida de ese comando únicamente te muestra la ruta de `/usr/bin/python` pero esta ruta es sólo un enlace simbólico a la versión de python que usas.